# Animated TV show about pirates in a future earth

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I remember watching a few episodes of an animated TV show set in a future version of the earth that was flooded. The main character was a pirate, sailing around the place. I think he had a tail.

This show would have been contemporary with the Gargoyles cartoon, so probably early 90's.

Does anyone know what it's called?

I remember it seemed to have a much better story than most of the TV cartoons around at the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some of the details are a bit mixed up, but this sounds a lot like a 1992 Hanna Barbera cartoon called [*The Pirates of Dark Water*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Dark_Water).

It takes place in an alien world, which strongly resembles Earth, but is being slowly destroyed by a substance called Dark Water; the protagonist is a pirate that is sailing around trying to find thirteen Treasures of Rule so he can fight back against the Dark Water.

[image]

He doesn't have a tail, but his friend is a strange bird/monkey combination that did:

[image]

The show did seem to have a more complex and involved storyline than usual; in particular, it had a story that seemed like it would have to have a resolution, and that carried over from episode to episode. Unfortunately, it was cancelled after only 21 episodes were aired.

Comment: I think that's it :)

Comment: I never saw the TV show, but I played the [awful Genesis game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjcVRAzKO9E)

Comment: OMG. I had no idea a game existed. @CreationEdge